How does client handle failures in RAFT-replicated datastores?
Consider a database like cockroachDB that uses RAFT protocol for replicating data to a replica group owning a partition of the data. How does a client handle a request that fails in such DBs? Because, in raft, an uncommitted entry could later get re-applied in case of a failover which promoted a node having that uncommitted entry in its log.

Would appreciate your help people! TIA

In the case of YugabyteDB, the client doesn't know about internal RAFT replication details. It can trust the db with success or error just like with a single node database with no replication. It will be considered a bug on the db otherwise.
For more details, please describe in detail the exact scenario you had in mind.

I want to know how does client stay independent of the fact that RAFT is being used internally, since, it is possible in these datastores that a wrote request fails to replicate to a majority quorum and the client receives a failure for it. But, just after that, a failover happens and the node that did get that request replicated in its log becomes the leader, thereby committing that entry into the datastore. This is inconsistent from a client's perspective.

@Dumb_Pegasus same thing that happens when you do a commit in a normal rdbms without replication, it commits to disk, and an error happens after-the-commit but before-the-client-got-the-commit-success. The client also didn't get the ACK but the data was persisted to WAL. So same behaviour, agree?

But in this case, if the operation had actually failed at that time, there is no way that rdbms will be able to apply it without the client retrying that transaction.

Whereas, in raft, the case that I have shared, the operation could be applied in future without the client retrying explicitly. This is what seems to be inconsistent to me.

Anything on this @dh YB?


Because, in raft, an uncommitted entry could later get re-applied in case of a failover which promoted a node having that uncommitted entry in its log.

--
The same can happen in 1-node-PostgreSQL. The write is applied to WAL, commited to disk, and the db fails before returning success to the client. The client gets an error. The db restarts, recovers from WAL, the write IS applied even though the client got an error. The client didn't retry, it got an error and the write went through.

Theoretically, yes this is same behaviour. But consider this, let's say that the network is reliable enough to ignore these transient message losses.  In this case, if postgres client recieved an error, it is fairly indicative of the operation being unsuccessful. Yet, in raft, we wouldn't know. What are your thoughts on this ? @dh YB


In this case, if postgres client recieved an error, it is fairly indicative of the operation being unsuccessful.

It's a "maybe" in all cases. Or see Franck Answer.
Please don't invent new unimaginable scenarios. Reality is complex enough as it is. This exact same scenario will happen in normal rdbms, nothing special about RAFT.

Not sure how the last scenario I described is "unimaginable". Typically, our app servers and DB servers would be deployed in the same vpc with a high bandwidth. This would keep the network issues to a minimum, yet the hardware can always fail AND is much more likely to fail.
I think it is a perfectly valid scenario that is yet unanswered. Also, this same scenario when applied to rdbms, because of a single master, ensures that a write cannot be reapplied later.

From core devs:
1.The error back to the client would be a timeout - which should be interpreted as an outcome unknown. Similar problem exists in traditional databases as well - where the IO for COMMIT may not have flushed to disk and the client timed out or got disconnected - the outcome would be unknown.


If both (assuming RF3) of the followers accepted the Raft record containing the write but their replies are lost then the new leader will be one of the previous followers and commit the record, making the write successful.   As part of this, it will notify the other follower that the Raft record is committed.  It will also send the Raft record to the old follower and tell it it was committed.


The client talks to the Raft leader. If it detects an error it may retry, but it keeps an id of the request and the case you described may receive an error like this one in YugabyteDB:
ERROR:  Duplicate request 126674 from client 08b09407-d78e-4c10-982f-be446d9a4e87 (min running 126674)
When using the PostgreSQL compatible API (YSQL) of YugabyteDB, the Raft client is the PostgreSQL backend. If the database client (the application) encounters an error when it runs a COMMIT operation, it may need to retry the transaction. In this scenario, as there is no ID, the application must ensure that the transaction is idempotent if it retries. In SQL, integrity constraints may provide protection against such situations, but it's important to consider additional checks that may be necessary for automatic retries.

I think you have misunderstood my question. I am not concerned about how it would maintain idempotency, rather, how would a client know that if an operation has failed currently, it will not be reapplied to the datastore without the client retrying the same transaction.

OK, if the client receives an error, it guarantees it has failed. This info comes from the Raft leader, which is responsible for the completion of the write, so there's no possibility that it is later reapplied.

For CockroachDB, a certain error code (40001) is returned, which signals to the caller that there is a retryable transaction error. The client is then expected to retry, just like some answers above indicate.
Docs here: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/common-errors#restart-transaction

Let me try to understand your question in detail.
Success Scenario on RF3:

Phase 1 (Synchronous):

A write operation is sent to the Raft leader.
The Raft leader writes the operation to its Write-Ahead Log (WAL) and sends it parallel to two followers.
One follower acknowledges the receipt of the write.
The leader applies the WAL to its datastore and confirms that the write was successful.


Phase 2 (Asynchronous):

Later (during the next operation or heartbeat), the leader commits the write operation to the followers, who then update their datastores.



If the leader dies before completing the second phase, the two followers will elect a new leader. One follower knows that it acknowledged the uncommitted log from the old leader. With this follower plus the old leader, it reaches the quorum. The log was effectively committed.
Failure Scenario
However, if the follower's acknowledgment did not reach the leader before the timeout, the leader might report the write operation as unsuccessful. This scenario leads to a situation where an error was reported, but the write was applied (two peers have it in their log).
As a result, the client may attempt to retry the request with the new leader due to the error. As I mentioned above, this can cause an ERROR: Duplicate request message to occur.
Suppose it doesn't retry (say all nodes crashed simultaneously). In that case, we don't know if the failure happened before or after committing the write operation to the database. As mentioned by Dorian, this occurs with any database that gets an error for a commit operation and it is unrelated to Raft.

Actually Frank, I'm considering a scenerio, which I think can be very common, where let's assume the network is fine, so there are no dropped messages.  Now, the leader receives req1, it fails to replicate to followers due to hardware issue but appends it locally and returns failure to the client. Then, it receives req2, at this point, the leader will try to replicate req1 as well for log matching property, right?  This means that only RAFT, due to how it works, would try to reapply a previously failed operation.

Appreciate you helping me with this @Frank
